# javascript object parsing and creating new object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following object.

```
{
  itemName: [ 'hard drive', 'fafa' ],
  itemValue: [ '383.00', '565' ],
  itemQuantity: [ '61626', '65' ],
}
```

How do I turn it to this object array below?

```
    {
        items: [
            {itemName : 'hard drive', itemValue : '383.00', itemQuantity : '61626'},
            {itemName : 'fafa', itemValue : '565', itemQuantity : '65'},
        ]
    }
```

Comment: You mean into a JSON Object?

Comment: @Gilles-AntoineNys - no, into a javascript object.  JSON is a string representation of data, and can represent an array, object, collection, etc.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the keys/values pairs (entries) from the object using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). Iterate the entries with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Inside the reduce, iterate the `values` with [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and check if an object exists in the result array (`result`) in the current index (`index`), if not add an empty one. Add the current key (`key`) and the current (`value`) to the object.

```js
const data = {
  itemName: [ 'hard drive', 'fafa' ],
  itemValue: [ '383.00', '565' ],
  itemQuantity: [ '61626', '65' ],
};

const result = Object.entries(data)
  .reduce((result, [key, values]) => {
    values.forEach((value, index) => {
      if(!result[index]) result[index] = {};
      
      result[index][key] = value;
    });
  
    return result;
  }, []);
  
console.log({ items: result });
```

Comment: Upvoted, but I think it's worth noting that this requires ES6, which isn't necessarily always available (eh-hem, IE11).... http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: @cale_b May be OP is working with server side JS and browser is not an issue :)

Comment: Again - **may be**, but it's worth _noting_ in an anwer that uses ES6 that it's an ES6-only answer.  Maybe OP has _no idea_ what is / is not compatible.  (Maybe that's why OP is here asking?)

Comment: @cale_b Anyway its upto Ori. Its his post but for me this solution is fine.

Comment: @cale_b - I agree. That's why I add links to everything I use. Since the links are to MDN, at the bottom of each article you can find a browser compatibility table. I'm not stating that it's ES6 because it's not ES6 (`Object.entries()` is ES2017), and today with the transpilers, and the browser support it's really blurred.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply loop over it, for a straight-forward solution:

```js
const object = {
  itemName: [ 'hard drive', 'fafa' ],
  itemValue: [ '383.00', '565' ],
  itemQuantity: [ '61626', '65' ],
};

const items = [];
for (let i = 0; i < object.itemName.length; i += 1) {
  items.push({
    itemName: object.itemName[i],
    itemValue: object.itemValue[i],
    itemQuantity: object.itemQuantity[i],
  });
}

console.log(items);
```

Comment: This was my initial thought, but what if there's multiple items with the same name?

Comment: You mean for example if the array `itemName` contains `['hard drive', 'foo', 'hard drive', 'hard drive']`? Do you need uniqueness in any way? Or could you give an example?

Comment: I'm just here reviewing, I'm not the person who asked the question.... but that's a valid question, I think....